# Spilt at the beginning of the word, or at the end of following text until the next occurrence

Tags: javascript

I need to split a string each time a word ends with the same last five letters, but remove the delimiter before that word.

So I started to make progress with:

```
arr = string.split(/(?=ology\b)/);
```

This keeps the ology which is great but splits it at the wrong place.

```
string = 'anthropology 1234; 2345; 5467; microbiology 5492; anthropology MGH MJH'

//this should look like ['anthropology 1234; 2345; 5467', 'microbiology 5492',  'anthropology MGH MJH'];
```

Comment: Your title is misleading: You don't actually want it to split at the end of the word, you want it to split at the _beginning_ of the word, or at the end of _following text_ until the next occurrence.

Comment: Also - I would challenge if you actually only want words that end with `ology` - you probably want a different pattern (maybe a word over X characters, not all uppercase, or similar)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pattern to search:

> A space that is followed by a word that has following string

```js
var string = 'anthropology 1234; 2345; 5467; microbiology 5492; anthropology MGH MJH'
var arr = string.split(/\s+(?=\w+ology\b)/);

console.log(arr)
```

As kindly suggested by **[cale-b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/870729/cale-b)**, following is a link for [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZffNFu/1) which provides good explanation of used regex and you can even play with it for other inputs.